# JS message on web page in IE

Tags: javascript, dom-events

How is the below error to be resolved. Should the div be in the form?

```
<script>

 function EvalSound(soundobj) {

  var thissound= eval("document."+soundobj);
  thissound.Play();
 }
</script>

<div id="s_player" style="display:block;width:620px;height:53px;">
<embed src="/media/a.wav" autostart=false width=0 height=0 id="sound1" enablejavascript="true">

<a href="#" onclick="javascript:EvalSound('sound1');">   <b>Play test sound</b></a></td>
</div>
```

**Error is**:

Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; GTB6.6; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.648; .NET CLR 3.5.21022; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; InfoPath.2; FDM)
Timestamp: Wed, 29 Dec 2010 14:22:09 UTC

> Message: 'undefined' is null or not an object

Comment: What does this have to do with jQuery?

Comment: And *really* what does it have to do with jQuery UI?

Answer (score 2):

Several things you can correct there:

1) Don't use `eval` to look up properties

```
var thissound= eval("document."+soundobj);
```

becomes

```
var thissound= document[soundobj];
```

2) **But**, if something has an `id`, use `document.getElementById` to look it up instead, so:

```
var thissound = document.getElementById(soundobj);
```

3) You don't use a `javascript:` prefix on event handler attributes, so

```
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:EvalSound('sound1');">
```

becomes

```
<a href="#" onclick="EvalSound('sound1');">
```

(although that one is largely harmless, it just defines a label you never use). (You only use the `javacript:` pseudo-protocol on link attributes, like `href`.)

**Update**: You've indicated none of the above did it, so:

4) Is `sound1` **really** unique?

Do you have *anything* else on the page called "sound1"? IE has issues with [mixing together namespaces](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/03/by-any-other-name-would-smell-as-sweet.html). Even just a variable with that name at page scope can cause issues.

**Further update**:

5) Can you use `embed` with IE?

I'm not at all sure you can, I thought IE wanted `object` rather than `embed`. [This page](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winforms/thread/f3608cdd-3296-4c99-ad33-c82a832658f4) is interesting vis-a-vis playing sounds in IE, looks like IE may have a script built into it to load objects like this; looking at the content of the script may well help you figure out what you need to do.

X) Walk through it

Your best bet for figuring this out is to walk through the code with a debugger (IE8 has dev tools built in, or you can use the free version of VS.Net). That will help you narrow down where the problem is. It sounds (no pun) as though the `sound1` element isn't being found, but really, it could be any of several things. If it's that the element isn't being found, my guess is that #5 is the culprit.

---

**Possibly off-topic**: You've tagged your question `jquery`. If you're really using jQuery, you can probably get more use out of it than you currently seem to be. For instance, you could use jQuery to set up the event handler rather than using `onclick`, which is very old-fashioned, and you could use jQuery instead of `document.getElementById` although in this specific case it doesn't buy you anything.

Comment: It didnt fix the problem as yet

Comment: @Rajeev: So you've already changed all of the above, and the problem persists? Okay, adding a fourth item. And are you sure the sound file is being found?

Comment: Yup the file is found,since i could play it on firefox.Also sound1 is the unique id

Comment: @Rajeev: I don't only mean IDs. Read the linked article, IE mixes a bunch of things together it shouldn't.

Comment: @Rajeev: Added a couple of final thoughts. Good luck with it.

Comment: @Rajeev: I don't know, I haven't had to play sounds in web pages. I know about the `embed` / `object` thing from other stuff, and the other issues aren't specific to audio. Bet you're looking forward to the `audio` tag, eh? Sadly, no IE support until IE9...

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
document.getElementByID(soundobj)
```

instead of document.soundobj

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script>

 function EvalSound(soundobj) {

  var thissound= document.getElementById(soundobj);
  thissound.Play();
 }
 </script>
```

Comment: It didnt fix the problem as yet